# Create a Project Template in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to create a project template in Visual Studio Team Services?  Specifically, I'm looking to bring in property-level permissions and build definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is no way to create a project template.

But there has an user voice [Support cloning of VSTS Projects](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17006419-support-cloning-of-vsts-projects) which suggest the similar feature, you can vote and follow up.

And for acount level build templates, you can develop your own extensions. More details please refer the achieved user voice [VSO build vnext: share build templates between projects](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/8468566-vso-build-vnext-share-build-templates-between-pro).