# Can I create a project template in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

My company creates a lot of projects in Azure DevOps, and they all have the same structure -- same members, same permissions.  Each project has different Git repositories within it, but that's the only thing (other than the name) that differs between them.  It would be helpful to have a template so that everything is set up correctly each time we need a new one.

I don't see a way to do this through the web interface.  I have the sense that I could probably do it with a script, but I don't know where to begin with that (including which tool to use).  Where should I start?

Comment: Apparently I asked this same basic question a year and a half ago.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239515/create-a-project-template-in-visual-studio-team-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish most of the configuration by script. For the beginning you might take a look at the [Azure Devops CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops), which allows you to perform several actions on Azure Devops, like:

- Create projects, Users and configure security
- Create repositories, pipelines and set branch permissions
- Create and manage work items
- ...

Comment: Thank you, yes.  After doing some more research, I think this is the correct answer.  We don't have an Azure subscription, though, so it won't work for me.  I'll probably just consolidate our stuff into a single project.   I appreciate the response.

Comment: As of now, I can confirm this tool still works. One limitation that would prevent me from using it is that it didn't transfer Styles or Board Columns or some other settings.

Comment: As I cannnot create an edit as the queue is full, here the update link for the Azure DevOps CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is now a way to do this without the Azure DevOps CLI (as long as your project that you want to template is one of the supported types (Agile, Scrum and Basic)). There is a tool available [here](https://vstsdemodata.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOpsDemoGenerator/_wiki/wikis/AzureDevOpsGenerator.wiki/58/Build-your-own-template) that will step you through the process.

There is also an excellent blog post [here](https://gregorsuttie.com/2020/04/30/azure-devops-best-practice-template-project/) that gives you an overview.

Comment: Very Nice article @Matt Stannett